# PHP: Remove all chars before the dot (incl. ".")

Tags: php, mongodb

What's the **fastest** method, to remove all characters before a dotted string ?

```
mongodatabase.collection_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

```
$result = strstr($collection, '.');
```

That would give you the desired result including the dot, so you would have to shift or trim the result to get rid of it.

For example:

```
$result = ltrim(strstr($collection, '.'), '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the two implementations and try those with microtime (timestamp in microseconds). With that, you could calculate the fastest method with your own DB !

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be:

```
$collection = preg_replace('/^.*\./', '', $collection);
```

Where `^` is the start of the subject, and `.*` matches anything until `\.` the literal dot character.

If it's assured that there is always a dot in the string, then you can also use a string function:

```
$collection = substr($collection, strpos($collection, ".") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using explode?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$collection = explode('.', $collection);

$result = $collection[1];
```

The only problem would be if there were other `.` in your `$collection` variable as these will cause the string to be split again, althought I believe if you do `$collection = explode('.', $collection, 2);` then that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression, your one doesn't work. This may be not the fastest way:

```
preg_replace('/^[a-z]+./', '', $collection);
```

Comment: The OP wants to skip all characters, this will only trim lower-cased letters and one additional character (the dot is not escaped). A name such as `database1.collection` would become `.collection` with this expression.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your regex is broken. Regex should be avoided if possible. Here is an alternative:

```
$collection="mongodatabase.collection_name";
echo substr($collection,strpos($collection,".")+1);
```

collection_name